# Is it possible to induce protein activation via frequency-specific mechanical waves?

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, biophysics

Would it be possible to induce shape changes in specific proteins by providing specific frequencies of mechanical waves in a thermostatically controlled environment such that those proteins may be activated without requiring regular ligand binding?

Answer (score 1):

This should defentily be possible and most likely already exists in the form of touch or pain receptors.

In the case of [mechanical nocireceptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nociceptor#Mechanical), which sense pressure or other mechanical changes in the tissue to signal pain, it's quite likely that there are distinct channel proteins that can correspond to mechanical deformation/pressure/etc, but I couldn't find any specifically known protein.

Most [touch receptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutaneous_receptor) seem to be based on bigger structures made up by neurons, so I'm not sure if they have one specific protein that senses mechanical movement, but I also wouldn't exclude that option - especially since almost nothing is known about non-human/mammalian touch receptors.